# .htaccess reserved words? / "directory" in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file (or some other part of apache) does not seem to want to allow the word "directory" in the URL.

Here's the key bits from my .htaccess file along with some notes about how it's operating:

```
RewriteBase /

#SEND "provider/chat" TO provider_chat.php
RewriteRule ^provider/chat$ provider_chat.php [PT]
#This works as expected

#SEND "directory/[alias]" TO directory.php
RewriteRule ^directory/[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,16}$ directory.php [PT]
#Gives me a 404 error.  But if I change it to ^director/..... and change the URL accordingly it works

#SEND "[alias]" or "directory" TO directory.php
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,16}$ directory.php [PT]
#works when I put any URL *except* /directory
```

To summarize the above...

If my URL is: [www.mydomain.com/directory](http://www.mydomain.com/directory)
I get a 404 error.

If my URL is: [www.mydomain.com/director](http://www.mydomain.com/director)
The redirect stuff works fine

When I get the 404 Error my apache logs show:

`[negotiation:error] [pid 29039] [client my.ip.address:34450] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/directory (None could be negotiated).`

So perhaps when /directory is in the url like that the .htaccess file isn't being considered at all for some reason?  It's a little hard to search through my other apache config files because the word "directory" is used so often there.

Any ideas?

(Note, there are at least two questions on S.O. with almost a similar title but neither provided much insight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have starting path as `/directory` and there is a file called `directory.php`, apache is most likely trying content negotiation due to presence of option `MultiViews`.

You can put this at the top of your .htaccess to turn it off:

```
Options -MultiViews
```